# KeyListener no me detecta la tecla al pulsarla

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy tratando de hacer un programa que me mueva una imagen. Esta imagen se mueve en un tablero creado a partir de un array bidimensional de casillas. Esta imagen se mueve por el tablero dependiendo de qué flechita pulse.

Lo que hago es, dependiendo de la flecha que se ha pulsado, le envio unos enteros o otros para que se sumen a sus coordenadas.

```
 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                tl.moverHormiga(-1, 0);
            }
            if (event.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                tl.moverHormiga(0, 1);
            }
            if (event.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                tl.moverHormiga(+1, 0);
            }
            if (event.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                tl.moverHormiga(0, -1);
            }
            repaint();
        }
```

El problema reside que, al iniciar el programa, todo va bien. el único problema es que no me detecta cuando pulso cualquier flecha. 
Este `KeyEvent` lo tengo en el método siguiente:

```
public void IniciComp() {

    tl = new Tablero();
    this.tl.setVisible(true);
    this.getContentPane().add(tl);
    this.getContentPane().addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event) {
            System.out.println("keyTyped");
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                tl.moverHormiga(-1, 0);
            }
            if (event.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                tl.moverHormiga(0, 1);
            }
            if (event.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                tl.moverHormiga(+1, 0);
            }
            if (event.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                tl.moverHormiga(0, -1);
            }
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {
        }         
    });
}
```

Y este método lo tengo en el constructor de la clase principal:

```
  //Constructor de la classe principal.
public ejercicioHormiga() {
    super("HORMIGA"); //Titulo
    IniciComp(); //Inicia los componentes
    setSize(900, 900); //Tamaño
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(TallerEvaluable2.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo he solucionado, el problema residía en que ese evento no lo implementaba en el `inicioComponentes` con el `implements KeyListener`.

De manera que he metido los `keyTyped`, `keyPressed` y `keyReleased` en un método que lo llevaba implementado:

```
 class keyb implements KeyListener {

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event) {
        System.out.println("KeyTyped");
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            tl.moverHormiga(0, -1);
        }
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            tl.moverHormiga(1, 0);
        }
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            tl.moverHormiga(0, 1);
        }
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            tl.moverHormiga(-1, 0);
        }
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
        System.out.println("keyPressed");
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            tl.moverHormiga(0, -1);
        }
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            tl.moverHormiga(1, 0);
        }
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            tl.moverHormiga(0, 1);
        }
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            tl.moverHormiga(-1, 0);
        }
        repaint();       
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {
        System.out.println("keyReleased");
    }

}
```

Y este método lo añado al `inicioComponentes` :

```
    public void IniciComp() {
     ...
     this.addKeyListener(new keyb());
     ...
}
```